# Xamarin Android Binding Multiple AARs unable to access resources

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin-binding

I am trying to make an Android Xamarin Binding Library (for [Zendesk](https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/android/welcome)). The initial problem is that this library is a multiple AAR project. The standard problem is that the binding library can only bind to one AAR at a time. If there are multiple AARs, then the binding will only occur for one of them (the newest one added from my experience). ([Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44573), [Xamarin.Forums on AAR](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/32324/aar-binding-type-or-namespace-could-not-be-found), many others can be found).

Keep in mind, with everything I say below, there are a lot of Jar files that needs to be added in as EmbeddedReferenceJars.

I first tried to put all of the files into a single folder (and name them from the folder they came from), and combine any resources into a single folder.[image: Zendesk Flat Folder Structure]
I zipped that up, renamed the zip folder into an AAR and tried to bind the project. After doing some things in *metadata.xml* and what not, I successfully compile the binding project with warnings, but the test app runs into the problem stated below.

From there, I decided to try to see what would happen if I put each AAR into this folder unzipped, and see the result (I had to put the classes.jar at the main level to try to bind). [image: Zendesk Tree Folder Structure]
I zipped that up, renamed it into an AAR and tried to bind the project. After some minor edits, I successfully compile the binding project with warnings, but the test app runs into the problem stated below.

The next thing I tried is To make an Binding Project for each AAR, and in each binding project, put the other AAR's classes.jar file as an EmbeddedReferenceJar so that it could build. Again: I run into the problem stated below.

The problem that I keep running into is that the R file from the binding is not being compiled, and will not allow for the test app to compile. (i.e. can't find string `@string/contact_fragment_title`, which I can confirm is both in the *values.xml* and *R.txt* file). I have tried to put the strings into my personal Strings file on the test project, or just removing the references to this strings altogether. When I do so, I can compile the test app, but I get an error stating that `com.zendesk.sdk.R$attr NoClassDefFoundError`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. And if I need to clarify anything (my writing is horrible), feel free to ask.